# Why can't I create an ORACLE 12c report with multiple images?

Tags: oracle, image, report, oracle12c, oraclereports

We have an 11g ORACLE Forms/Reports application. Some reports have multiple images which work fine in 11g, but when we move them to our new 12c environment, the report hangs.

Experimentation shows that when all images bar one is removed, the report runs ok. You can introduce multiple copies of the same image into the report and it will still run, but if you have a mix of images, it hangs. It does not matter if the images are linked in or inserted, or in what order or where, it still fails.

By hanging, I mean that the report server says that the report is formatting page X (where X is the page containing the second image), and you cannot cancel the report. Trace logs show that the failure occurs when it is processing an image.

Since I have seen no complaints about 12c images on the web, I assume it is not an ORACLE bug, and I also assume that such a restriction cannot be a feature. I assume that some setting is restricting the number of images which can be processed. Does anyone know what that setting is and how to lift it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have *solution*, but I do have a few *suggestions*:

- recompile the report using "all" option (`Ctrl + Shift + K`). Sometimes it makes *magic*
- I've noticed similar behavior when image size is (too) large; try to make it smaller (how? For example, reduce its quality) (what is "too large"? It depends; to me, it happened when report had several thousands of pages, displaying relatively small images (e.g. 20 KB in size) but - multiplied by number of pages, it just didn't work. Image size reduced to ~4KB fixed it. I'm not saying that you can do the same, but - if possible, try it

I agree - the fact that the same report works OK on 11g makes you *crazy*, huh ... I sincerely hope that compilation will help as it is the simplest option I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for your interest and rapid response. Unfortunately, I am already compiling all. Size is not the issue. Even a small report with just 2 small images will fail if the images are different.

Comment: Huh, that's bad news. Unfortunately, I don't have any other ideas. Perhaps - if you can - to create a brand new report, from scratch? Don't make it *fancy*, just try to make it *work*. Maybe there's something wrong with this very report, but a new "copy" will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a near identical report in a near identical application, which worked. By creating a report with 2 images which could run in either application, and changing the applications so they used the same report server, I found that the test report worked in 1 app but hung in the other. The only difference then lay in how the report was submitted. For the hanging report, I rewrote the submission code from scratch and the report worked fine. I still don't know the critical difference, but now it doesn't matter.

Comment: Well it still matters as we also have batch jobs running these reports and they use a different method of submission (UTL_HTTP.REQUEST) and the multiple-image reports now fail there. I want to rewrite this using SRW routines, but I need to wait for these packages to get installed. Am I wasting my time with SRW?

Comment: A little rant: I have been writing forms and reports since Forms 2/ReportWriter 1, and I have never seen a Forms/Reports version as flaky as 12c. Change my mind.